# multiple string literals to const char* in same assignment statement

Tags: c++, string

I'm new to c++ and I came across below code snippet which looks strange for me.

```
const char* keys = "hello" "world";
std::cout << keys << std::endl;
```

Above code prints **helloworld** in the console. Is it syntactically valid to assign two string literals to a const char* in the same statement? if so, how it will be stored in memory?

Comment: "hello" "world" == "helloworld"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a rule of C++ (and C) adjacent string literals are concatenated prior to compilation (but after macro expansion IIRC).

This happens anywhere, not just as part of an assignment statement.

Comment: so the string literals are concatenated prior to compilation and stored contiguously in read only data segment.

Comment: They're stored contiguously, but using a read only data segment is an implementation detail that won't be true for some systems.

Answer (score 4):

A character sequence within quotes (or even empty quotes) with or without an encoding prefix is a string-literal as per [[lex.string]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.string).

And as per [[lex.string]/13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.string#13):

> ...adjacent string-literals are concatenated.

So

```
const char* keys = "hello" "world";
```

is same as:

```
const char* keys = "helloworld";
```